# Differentiability of $f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

What does it mean for a function such as $$f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$$

to be differentiable?

Do we only require that all partial derivatives are continuous?
Does the jacobian also need to be defined at all points? (Is that analogous with the partial derivatives being continuous?)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: the partial derivatives doesnt **need** to be continuous for $f$ being differentiable. It is a sufficient condition only. Also that the jacobian matrix exists at all points doesnt mean that $f$ is differentiable at all points. Check Fréchet derivative in wikipedia or google.

Comment: If you consider something like $\textbf{f}(x,y) = (f_1,f_2)$ where $f_1(x,y) = f_2(x,y) = \textbf{1}_{\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x=y\}}$, then the partials of $f_1, f_2$ at $0$ exist and are $0$ (hence the Jacobian is well-defined) but the $\textbf{f}(x,y)$ isn't differentiable since its component functions aren't even continuous.

Comment: Partial derivatives being continuous isn't a necessary condition for differentiability. Consider $f(x,y)$ which maps $(x,y)$ to $(x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}, x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x})$ where $f = (0,0)$ if $x=0$. The Jacobian does need to be defined, however (this is equivalent to stating that the partials _exist_). Basically, differentiability states that the linear approximation defined by the Jacobian is a good approximation to $f$.